# Using VBA to automatically shade between two series on an XY scatterplot

Tags: excel, scatter-plot, vba

I'm creating an interactive workbook for citizen scientists regarding water quality. There's one graph that is used to visualize the "base flow" of the stream. The graph shows a cross-sectional of the stream where the black is the stream bed shape, and the blue line marks the water level in the stream bed.

My desire is to both "color-in" the stream bed below the black line, and the water between the blue and black lines. I tried looking up suggestions on Google where I found this link: https://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/VBAdraw.html, but the portion that would contain my desired answer has a broken link.

I want to use VBA since this graph would need to be generated each time a group opens the workbook to create their base flow data, and not all of these users are excel savvy to do it through menus. There will also be a variety of cross-sections since these measurements are happening on different streams.

Here is some example data being used to create these visual charts:

[image: example data used]

Comment: Do you know how to do it manually? If so, use the "Record Macro" function and manually format a chart how you want. That will give you a good starting point of what the commands and color codes are in VBA.

Comment: Never knew there was such a function. That's a great idea! Thank you! I'll see what I can do with "Record Macro"

Comment: It will give you very specific VBA code with lots of Selects/activates, so it will need to be adapted to be more robust, but it will give you the meat of it. If you get stuck adapting, feel free to post the code you've got so far and what you're stuck on and I'm sure you will get more help.

Comment: This worked out perfectly! Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe what you want is in my more recent tutorial, [Fill Under or Between Series in an Excel XY Chart](https://peltiertech.com/fill-under-between-series-in-excel-chart/).